How to extract text parts from a large project?
I need to implement a new language on a website that was written in one language (for example, in English). Now I need to add the ability to change the language on the site, for example, choosing between English and Spanish or any other language.
My idea is to create a table in the database that contains "key," "language 1," and "language 2." Initially, when the site loads, I download all the records from the table and create a method for each parent component; this file will be used in all child components. The principle of this method is simple: before rendering the page, this method will be called in every place where there is a key. The key is the name of the variable that will replace the static text in the HTML or JS code.
Method:
babelfishTranslate(text) {
  if (this.wordReplacements[text]) {
    return this.wordReplacements[text];
  } else {
    return text;
  }
}

Example:
<div class="align-items-center align-items-md-end d-flex justify-content-between">
  <h5 class="fw-bold">
    {{ $root.babelfishTranslate(incipitdata.titolo || "incipit1") }}, {{ nomeAzienda }}
  </h5>
  <div class="d-flex gap-3 align-items-center">
    <div class="d-flex gap-3">
      <div>{{ $root.babelfishTranslate("incipit2") }}</div>
      <switcher 
        :idvalore="'modalitaPrivacy'" 
        :name="'modalitaPrivacy'" 
        :valore="modalitaPrivacy" 
        v-on:settavalore="settaValore" 
        :key="'modalitaPrivacy' + aggiornaSwitcher"
      />
    </div>
    <div
      v-tooltip="$root.babelfishTranslate('incipit3')"
      class="nascondiSeMobile"
      :key="aggiornaTooltip"
    >
      <button class="fs-2 btn btn-aggiungi color-custom" @click="vaiInModalitaModifica">
        <i class="fa-duotone fa-gear"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$root.babelfishTranslate(‘incipit2’) calls the babelfishTranslate method, which looks in the global variable where there is a translation if the key has the value ‘incipit2’, and replaces it with the user's chosen language.
Table:



Key
English
Italian




incipit2
Privacy mode
Modalità Privacy



But there is a problem with all of this. Replacing all the written static text with these "keys," variables that I will later record in the table with translations for "language 1" and "language 2."
How can I find all the text in my project? If I wrote the project in Vue 2, using the Options API, and all the HTML code is written inside the "template" variable. Also, it needs to take into account full phrases, for example, "Welcome [username], do you want to add [product name] to the cart?"

What you're describing is usually called a message catalog.

How do you find text in any software system? It's a manual process and you have to look at both code and markup.

@BohdanVoznyi You're reinventing the wheel with babelfishTranslate, this is what vue-i18n is for. Converting components to Vue SFCs prior to this could help you to make use of existing third-party tools that deal with i18n. The question currently lacks focus, your case was better shown in your previous edits, https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/79047013/1 . The answer is that you can't do this in any straightforward way, you'll have to write your own tools to process your code

If you don't have fully matching English phrases in the table, the first step would be to extract all component templates (if you have them all registered on one page, you can access them in a browser like Vue.options.components.CompName.options.template). Or use a regex to parse Vue.component("sortArrows", ... template: \...`)from codebase. The next step is to parse templates with some dom parser and extract all text nodes. Then you can process text further and replace the phrases witht('KEY')` in the codebase and double check and manually edit changes before committing them.
